# bind elements to touchstart and click

Tags: jquery, html, tablet

I have div slider which is not working on tap but on pc browser it is working fine .It is not working  because i have used onclick event i think .

but when i add ,

```
$('.sliderImage').live("click touchstart", function (event) {
    alert('click event is ' + event.type);
});
```

This in html so all div when clicked first this alert works and div is moving ... after removing this function moving is not working . is there any other method to bind elements to touch .

Comment: You shouldn't use `.live()` anymore, it's deprecated and removed in recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: Btw, a tap should also fire a `click` event, it's basically `touchstart` -> `touchend` -> `click` in that order.

Answer (score 1):

As jack said, use "on" instead of "live" as your bind method. You might want to consider detecting whether the device supports touch and using that as the basis for your binding. Some devices will trigger both click and touchstart leading to unpredictable effects.

```
/* Touch event support */
utils.POINTER_EVENT = (function() {
//check if the browser supports touch events
    var supportsTouch = 'createTouch' in document;
    //base our event names on the result...
    var obj = {
        START:  (supportsTouch) ? 'touchstart'  : 'mousedown',
        MOVE:   (supportsTouch) ? 'touchmove'   : 'mousemove',
        END:    (supportsTouch) ? 'touchend'    : 'mouseup',
    getPointerPosition: function(ev) { return { x: (supportsTouch) ? ev.touches[0].pageX : ev.pageX, y: (supportsTouch) ? ev.touches[0].pageY : ev.pageY }; }
    };
    return obj;
})();
```

Then bind to utils.POINTER_EVENT